# LocalStorage is working only in 1 page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

tried to showing value of my localstorage, but result is

> undefined

lets say i set my local storage in `login.js` and i want to call my local storage value in `dasboard.js`

i set my localstorage like this : `window.localStorage['username'];`

and i called like this : `$(".myClass").html(localStorage['username']);`

what's wrong with my code?

*note: i tried call other ways, like :
`storage.getItem('username');`
`localStorage['username']`

but result is the same... Help me

thanks

Comment: `window.localstorage` vs `window.localStorage` ?

Comment: can you copy and paste those code in your question?

Comment: And also specify the browser you are using.

Comment: @HasanIbrahim i use Lastest Google Chrome browser, and also that's my trully code, but `window.localStorage['username'];` i saved in 1st page, and `$(".myClass").html(localStorage['username']);` on my second page

Comment: @DarkCode999 It must not be an issue with the page you are setting and the page you are accessing it. Unless you access it from a different application. But I don't see the value you have set against the 'username' key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems to be some typo mistake in code. please use readable code syntax.

```
   localStorage.setItem('username', 'xyz'); // set value
   var userName = localStorage.getItem('username') //get value
   $(".myClass").html(userName);
```

you can also use "window" prefix before it.
please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

hope this will help you.

Comment: is the `value` should always be a string ? cause i tried your method still get undefined.... i tried `localStorage.setItem('username', MyVar);`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are not setting it correctly.

Could you please try

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

`window.localStorage['username'];` is not setting it in localStorage(right hand side is missing). try this in the console and check application tab. this key won't get added to LS.

use `window.localStorage['username'] = 'some value';` otherwise.

for more info https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: here is my ss of my code, [link](http://pasteboard.co/8t9bWU424.png) , what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=html5&file=local-storage

```
    if(localStorage){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".save").click(function(){
            // Get input name
            var firstName = $("#firstName").val();

            // Store data
            localStorage.setItem("first_name", firstName);
            alert("Your first name is saved.");
        });
        $(".access").click(function(){
            // Retrieve data
            alert("Hi, " + localStorage.getItem("first_name"));
        });
    });
} else{
    alert("Sorry, your browser do not support local storage.");
}
```

Kindly check this example and let me know if it helps you out.

Comment: am i used too much localStorage in the same time ?? pls help, here my ss of my code : [ScreenShoots](http://pasteboard.co/8t9bWU424.png)

Comment: Actually we should not prefer localstorage often. 5 mb is the max size.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not communicating with the local storage api, when doing window.localStorage

to set a local storage item , use:

```
localStorage.setItem( "key", "value" );
```

to retrieve a local storage item, use:

```
localStorage.getItem( "key" );
```